# Behavior of scp command

Tags: linux

I am trying to do an scp (on SuSE LINUX) and seeing something that I did not expect.

```
scp -q -r /home/dir1/mydir host:/var/home/dirx/BACKUPS
```

If there is `/var/home/dirx/BACKUPS/mydir` under the destination host, I see that the existing directories under that directory (including modification times) are left untouched. Only new directories are created.

If there are files in the destination directory that do not exist in the source directory, they are preserved.

After the copy, I was expecting to see the destination directory as an exact copy of the source directory.  Seems like more of a merge.

Is that how scp supposed to work?

Comment: It seems you're looking for rsync, not scp. (rsync can work over SSH too.)

Comment: In particular, look at the --delete options.

Comment: Let me take a look at that.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's standard behavior for a copy command in pretty much any system. Files which exist in both locations will cause the destination to get refreshed with a source copy. Files which don't exist in the destination will be created/copied from the source.

Files which exist ONLY in the destination will not be affected, because it's not copy/cp's job to delete "stale" files - it has no way of knowing what a stale file is.

If you want to remove old/obsolete files in the destination, you'll need some other tool.

Comment: And that "other tool" is rsync.

Answer (score 0):

The other tool is ssh combined with tar.  This will do the trick if you want to completely scrap the target directory and recreate it.

```
( cd /home/dir1/mydir && tar cf - . ) | ssh host "cd /var/home/dirx && rm -rf BACKUPS && mkdir BACKUPS && cd BACKUPS && tar xvf -"
```